# Is applescript a dead language?

Tags: applescript

Does someone still use applescript, Apple archived the documentation and did not update the language for a lot of time. does it mean that the language is dead?

Comment: What's your definition of "dead"?

Comment: no more use, trashed by apple, no support...

Comment: i am not sure yet, i just want confirmation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole AppleScript stack has been in maintenance mode ever since Apple disbanded the Mac Automation team back in 2016 and (belatedly) fired the Product Manager that ran it into the ground. So, no, its future does not look bright, and it hasn’t for quite some time.

But at this point I recommend you wait a couple weeks before making any decisions. Mac Shortcuts should drop at WWDC 2020, at which point we’ll hopefully learn if Apple event IPC still has any support at Apple or if App Extensions’ crude “Duplo blocks” (which is what iOS Shortcuts uses) is the future of cross-platform automation now.